# SCP with PHP - Does not work

Tags: php, linux, debian, sftp, scp

Trying to upload a file to a different server using PHP. It connects with `ssh_connect()` successfully, but when I include `ssh2_scp_send` the page that is displayed is blank (as though there is a syntax error), and it certainly did not upload the file. Any idea why this may be? I'd prefer to use PHP, but if it doesn't work I suppose I could make a system call to CLI `scp` with private key files, but I'd prefer not to do that. Alternative suggestions are welcomed.

> Info: debian w/apache
>
> Installed: libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php php-pear php5-dev; pecl install -f ssh2

```
$ssh = ssh2_connect('localhost', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'user', 'password');
ssh2_scp_send($ssh, 'original', 'destination'); # does not work
ssh2_exec($ssh, 'exit'); #does not help
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to enable error_reporting to see the error: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+blank+page

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned this: both of these were set: ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd recommend using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
$sftp->put('filename.ext', 'hello, world!');
print_r($sftp->nlist());
?>
```

Chief among libssh2's problems is the fact that it's not easy to install.  The original authors have abandoned it.  The source code on php.net requires modification for it to even compile and although you can install it with apt-get on Ubuntu right now what happens when it requires more than just two new lines to work?  And what if the Linux box you're trying to get it working on isn't Ubuntu?

If you ever need to create a new server on which to host your website you don't want to be stuck spending hours on a bunch of esoteric dependencies.